# Passing object constructor parameters in Livebindings

Tags: delphi, livebindings

Are TListBindSourceAdapter and TObjectBindSourceAdapter able to create new objects whose constructors require parameters?  For example,

```
MyObject := TMyObject.Create(AParameter: TObject);
```

If yes, how can I code this?

Comment: Actually, my question more applies to TListBindSourceAdapter and inserting new records using TDbNavigator at runtime.

Comment: Why do you even need to create a new object when inserting new records into database? I have never heard of such approach.

Comment: @SilverWarior.  I am not creating an object to insert in the database.  Livebindings can automatically create objects when you bind a list to a grid and either click the insert button on a DBNavigator or when you move past the last record in the grid.  When it does, it uses a parameterless constructor.  My question is how I can inject parameters.